# How to call Laravel controller function from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, function, laravel-5, controller

How i can call controller function using JavaScript !?

Controller:

```
public function archive($id)
{
  $article = Article::find($id);

  $article->public = 0;
  $article->archive = 1;

  $article->save();
}
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/archive/{id}', 'HomeController@archive');
```

I would be grateful for any working options. Thank you!

Comment: Use an ajax call to access your rest route.

Comment: if i try to use an ajax call, i get error 405 (Method not allowed).
In data i also send csrf_token

Comment: You can send CSRF tokens with your AJAX requests. Read all about it: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: i send csrf token in request, but in this case nothing happens. I did't get any errors, and function call is not working

Answer (score 1):

I believe you also need to create response for your controller if you want to access it via api also.

```
// put this above your class name
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function archive(Request $request, $id)
{
  $article = Article::find($id);

  $article->public = 0;
  $article->archive = 1;

  $article->save();

  return response()->json([
    'success' => 'yes',
  ]);
}
```

Use `jQuery ajax` if you are using jQuery

```
$.post('/archive/' + {your_id}, function(response) {
    // handle your response here
    console.log(response);
})
```

Comment: in response i get this: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Could you check if that `your_id` is existed in your database. Or check your error log for more detail error.

Comment: Yes, it exists. I use this construction for tests `$.post('/archive/2',` but the error is the same

Comment: Check my edit also, maybe the problem is you don't have response? Could you check your error_log?

Comment: Tell me please where i can check error_log ? I'm new to laravel.
If i use `Route::get....` and `window.location...` it works for me , but i need update without refresh the page

Comment: I tried to use this construction `<button type="button" title="Change" onclick="$.ajax({'url':'/archive/2' ,'method':'POST',succes:function‌​(){}})">Change</button>`, but in this case i get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`, after i tried to add `<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">` and `'_token': $('#token').val()` , but i get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Comment: my laravel.log is empty, i didn't get any log

Comment: Open your `config/app.php` and add `APP_DEBUG=true`

Comment: Hmmm,  this is strange but app debug is true ! I also changed chmod to 777 for laravel.log

Comment: So did you have any ideas how to solve this issue ? Thanks!

Comment: Check your error log on your `nginx` or `apache` error log?
Did you also try to put `Request $request` as my edited answer?